# How to tell monolith code that AWS workers are all done

Tags: amazon-web-services

We're trying to convert our monolithic code base to AWS, but I'm having trouble finding a solution to the problem of telling the monolith when some parallel AWS work is done.

For instance, our code does something like this for a job:
1. Read in a data file.
2. Generate PDFs based on the data.
3. Do some other stuff.
4. Do stuff with those PDFs.

We want to break out step 2 into a faster, scalable process and for good or ill we decided to use AWS workers. We've got a decent plan for how to pass data through AWS and generate the PDfs in parallel, but we want the monolith to chug along on steps 2 and 3 and then pause at step 4 until some flag is set and it can continue the job once all of the PDFs have been generated.

A few ideas we had are: 1) Have an on-prem app that records the requests and replies in an on-prem database table and tells the monolith when everything is done. 2) Store the reply messages in a queue until the monolith says it's done with its requests, and then have an app read the replies until the number of job-related replies matches the number of given requests. Since multiple jobs can run at the same time we'd need to either filter the messages or generate a lot of temporary queues. 3) Same as 1, but have the database be in the AWS.

So, is there an obvious and/or more elegant solution to this problem? I can only assume this is a pretty common issue when trying to pull work out of a monolith.

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: Is the monolith in AWS? #2 seems like the worst solution, it would have an absolute ton of edge cases and potential pitfalls. But generally the question of inter-process signalling has a whole universe of potential solutions with various pros and cons that will depend a lot on the specifics of your situation.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

Use [AWS Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/features/) which can coordinate your PDF tasks and execute another task (like to send a message to your monolithic application) when the PDF tasks are complete.

**Option 2:**

Create a DynamoDB table to store PDF tasks. When creating the task record include the following attributes:

```
totalWorkers: #
completedWorkers: 0
```

When a worker is finished, have it update the record using [DynamoDB Atomic Counters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.AtomicCounters) to increment the `completedWorkers` attribute.

When `completedWorkers` equals `totalWorkers` you know the task is completed.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I think we'll be using DynamoDB.